# How was Plan B supposed to work?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

In the movie Interstellar, a backup plan was made in case the primary plan to evacuate earth failed. The plan entailed deployment of frozen human embryos on the new planet to essentially restart the human species.

How would this work? Human embryos don't work like plant seeds; you cant just throw them all over the place and expect new humans to be created. Even if you were able to create new human babies, how were they expected to survive with no shelter/food/protection on the new planet?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically they were going to raise the first generation with the resources from the **Endurance**.

As I understood them, they had the resources to have a few of the embryos developed in artificial wombs (you would chose these to be female embryos).

Once the team had raised these women, they would spend their years being surrogate mothers for more embryos.

There is a mention that they expected the third generation to have a population of at least 100, from which stable growth could naturally be expected.

At this point, the remaining embryos would gradually be used to provide genetic diversity in the new mankind.

Comment: 'artificial wombs' - Are these mentioned in the movie?

Comment: Plan B? This should have been called Plan Z.

Comment: @legomaker yes, they call them Incubators.